# Is it always safe to pass empty dict as keywords argument?

Tags: python, argument-passing

Are there any cases where

```
f(arg1, arg2..., argN)
```

works and produces a result and

```
f(arg1, arg2..., argN, **{} )
```

yields a different result, or causes an error?

I'm assuming that a `**kwds` doesn't already occur in the argument list.

The context is that I'm writing a functor that holds a function and it's arguments
for later evaluation, and want to support optional keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is always safe to do.  The two calls are completely equivalent, and the function `f()` has no way to distinguish them (except for introspecting the source code, of course).

Comment: Does the mutability of a `dict` not matter here?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: No, it will be copied before being passed in.

Comment: Thanks, I thought maybe something weird could happen if `f` were implemented in c

Comment: @Dave: No, not even then.  Internally, the function will get passed an empty dictionary of keyword arguments in *both* cases.